# How do I use Flex's Binding in a Flash AS3 project

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, binding

I have a flash app using the flex framework - I would like to bind a display object textField with data from my dataModel. 
How do I do this without the flex binding brackets "{ }"

Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `BindingUtils` class. For example, say you have an object `foo` with property `bar` that you want to bind to your text area's `text` property; all you need to do is the following in your ActionScript:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty( myTextArea, "text", foo, "bar" );
```

This will tell Flex to watch `foo` for any changes to the property `bar`, and when changes occur, copy the value to `myTextArea.text`.

Full documentation can be found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html).

Comment: Brilliant, but the mx.bindings package does not seem to be available for both my flex4 actionscript project or my flash as3. Which package have I not included into my application?

Comment: BindingUtils is located under the mx.binding.utils package and should be present in Flex 4.

Comment: My mistake I should have said, which flex lib swc? Currently I have, 'flex.swc', 'framework.swc', 'utilities.swc', 'flash-integration.swc'

Comment: Thank you buddy - I should be able to work it out from here. Maybe I just need to app-path to it again and recompile.

Comment: I love this! One odd thing is that it seems that if the property is bound in the MXML then this rebind seems to be reset back to the MXML when the data source is updated. I haven't confirmed that that is what happens, but it seems so.